# Load with addWebsiteFilter not working

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, programmatically, programming

I am working on product collection. Here is my query:

> $_product =
>   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->addWebsiteFilter($allWebsiteIds)->load($productid);

But this is not working.

As reference check this [link](http://www.anyknowledge.com/magento-get-details-of-child-products-from-the-parent-product-id-of-configurable-product/). I want to load detail in this line

> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);

but with "addWebsiteFilter" also.Any one know how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no method `addWebsiteFilter` for the product model.
The method is available for the product collection.

If you want to use `load` you have to do the check for website later.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$productWebsites = $product->getWebsiteIds();
```

Then you have to check if your websites are in the `$productWebsites`. do an `array_intersect` or something you need.

Comment: Ok and also any type of help on this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86114/programatically-get-product-collection-which-are-exists-in-array-of-website-ids